# How to make an efficient mysql index for WHERE x > 0

Tags: sql, mysql, indexing

I have a use case where my table has a couple of columns:

```
CREATE TABLE stocks (
    id INT,
    warehouse_id INT,
    product_id INT,
    quantity INT,
    updated_at DATETIIME
);
```

Almost all of my queries include `WHERE quantity > 0` and `ORDER BY updated_at`.
eg.

```
WHERE quantity > 0
AND warehouse_id = 11
ORDER BY updated_at DESC
```

or

```
WHERE quantity > 0
AND product_id = 1200
ORDER BY updated_at ASC
```

I know I can simply add an index on quantity, but that will prevent `ORDER BY` from using the index.
Is there a way to make an index that only stores 2 values: `quantity = 0` and `quantity > 0` so I can take advantage of it with both rules I mentioned above?

eg. for queries above:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_test1 ON stocks ("quantity > 0", product_id, updated_at)
CREATE INDEX idx_test2 ON stocks ("quantity > 0", warehouse_id, updated_at)
```

Answer (score 3):

Starting MySQL 8.0.13, you can create [a functional index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-functional-key-parts), which makes use of a function or expression.

Your pseudo-code:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_test1 ON stocks ("quantity > 0", product_id, updated_at);
```

Would translate as:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_test1 ON stocks ( ( quantity > 0 ), product_id, updated_at);
```

Expression `quantity > 0` yields `1` or `0` depending on whether the condition is fulfilled - which the index uses.

It is unsure whether this will actually improve the performance of the query; `0`/`1` values are typically inefficient to index, because there are just two possible values. You *might* want to try changing the order of the columns in the index, to put a more discriminating criteria first, so maybe:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_test1 ON stocks ( product_id, updated_at, ( quantity > 0 ));
```

You might also want to have the same index with `updated_at desc`, if your queries use that sort direction as well.

Comment: Looks like I managed to create the index, but mysql is not using it. It keeps trying less efficient indexes instead.

Comment: I believe that the "range" part (`updated_at`) needs to be last.  And that the other things in the index can be in either order with equal effectiveness.  This is the case for non-'functional' indexes.